# Flutter timepicker error: Don't use 'BuildContext's across async gaps. Try rewriting the code to not reference the 'BuildContext'

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting this error message from timepicker in my flutter app:

**Don't use 'BuildContext's across async gaps.
Try rewriting the code to not reference the 'BuildContext'.**

Here is the code I am using:

```
  if (selectedDay != null) {
timeOfDay = await showTimePicker(
    context: context,
    initialTime: TimeOfDay.fromDateTime(
      now.add(
        const Duration(minutes: 1),
      ),
    ),
    builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
      return Theme(
        data: ThemeData(
          colorScheme: const ColorScheme.light(
            primary: Colors.teal,
          ),
        ),
        child: child!,
      );
    });

if (timeOfDay != null) {
  return NotificationWeekAndTime(
      dayOfTheWeek: selectedDay!, timeOfDay: timeOfDay);
}
}
```

[image]

I have tried to add **if (!mounted) return;** but the error doesn't disappear. Does anyone know what I can do to solve it?

Comment: From where does your mounted variable come from? An if(context.mounted) { ...  timePickerLogic } should work.

Comment: using `mounted` only works in StatefulWidget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get rid of the warning, you may want to wrap the code in `if block` (following the doc at https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BuildContext/mounted.html):

```
if(context.mounted){

timeOfDay = await showDateTimePicker()
/// code continuation 


}
```